# From Illustrator to Photoshop to Print

Tags: print-design, export, png, jpg

I need to export final files with at max 128mb for print on fabric.

My initial canvas size is 16.383px x 10.000px (the 16383 is the max allowed by illustrator).

I've noticed that even working in 300dpi, when uploaded in jpg format, even if my canvas size is bigger that the final application, my dpi drops to 190.

That's why I'm making a huge canvas with 400dpi.

As my Illustrator says that the jpg is too large to be exported, I'm opening the .ai file in Photoshop and Save As jpg from there.

The jpg file is 17mb while a PNG file is 600mb.

What I can do to have the best quality? What I should do?

Thank you very much if someone can help me.

Comment: What are the physical dimensions of your project? What are you "uploading" to where? What dpi drops? Illustrator is vector based.

Answer (score 0):

This will probably not be the answer you are looking for, but aiming to solve your problem.

I doubt any "fabric" printing project will be beyond 1mt sqr. The idea for fabric design is to have a pattern. Ok, some big rolls of printed fabric can go 1.5m wide, but the drum printing then will be way below the 226 ish inches (more than 5mt.) of the limit of an illustrator canvas.

So I think you can simply make the project at real size.

Do not define a file inside Illustrator in pixels. Use physical units. If your project is too big to be accepted (Which I doubt is needed) make it on some scale.

---

For the exported file, ask the printer provider the requirements... before making your project. RGB? CMYK? Color Profile? Max TOC? File format?

PNG is for RGB, JPG can have both. Probably you need a TIF file.

Comment: The design i'm making is for apparel. There's clothes with 12.000 x 3.000 px. I'm making a huge canvas so I can use in all models regardless their size. The fact is that when I export and try to apply the image is smaller and with less pixels. My file is 16000x10000 with 400dpi but when applied to a canvas that has 11.000x3.000 goes with 192 dpi.... why?